# Unclosable session

Tags: java, mina

I've an `IoSession`, and when I call `close()` on it, it is still connected.

The code:

```java
restSession.close(true).awaitUninterruptibly(5000); //Stuck here, timeout is ignored
connector.dispose();    //Never happens :(
```

Some other version:

```java
restSession.close(true);
while (restSession.isConnected()) {
    System.out.println("REST is still connected!"); //Keeps spamming
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
connector.dispose();    //Never happens :(
```

Any idea why is this happening and how to solve it? Shouldn't `close(true)` just close it no matter what?